# tokens do not appear in wallet after contract creation

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, tokens, bsc

I'm doing the tests for creating a token. After compiling everything without any error, deploying and confirming it on the testnet network, the tokens do not appear in the wallet, and in testnet.bsc, the creation of the contract appears, but neither the token name nor the quantity appears. could anyone help me to solve this problem?
code I'm using:

```
pragma solidity >=0.5.10;

    library SafeMath {
      function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
      }
      function sub(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a);
        c = a - b;
      }
      function mul(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a * b;
        require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
      }
      function div(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
      }
    }
    
    contract BEP20Interface {
      function totalSupply() public view returns (uint);
      function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance);
      function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining);
      function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
      function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
      function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
    
      event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
      event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
    }
    
    contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
      function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes memory data) public;
    }
    
    contract Owned {
      address public owner;
      address public newOwner;
    
      event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);
    
      constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
      }
    
      modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
      }
    
      function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        newOwner = _newOwner;
      }
      function acceptOwnership() public {
        require(msg.sender == newOwner);
        emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
        owner = newOwner;
        newOwner = address(0);
      }
    }
    
    contract TokenBEP20 is BEP20Interface, Owned{
      using SafeMath for uint;
    
      string public symbol;
      string public name;
      uint8 public decimals;
      uint _totalSupply;
    
      mapping(address => uint) balances;
      mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;
    
      constructor() public {
        symbol = "XXX";
        name = "XXX";
        decimals = 9;
        _totalSupply =  100;
        balances[owner] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), owner, _totalSupply);
      }
    
      function totalSupply() public view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply.sub(balances[address(0)]);
      }
      function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) {
          return balances[tokenOwner];
      }
      function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
      }
      function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
      }
      function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = allowed[from][msg.sender].sub(tokens);
        balances[to] = balances[to].add(tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
      }
      function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
      }
      function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes memory data) public returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, address(this), data);
        return true;
      }
      function () external payable {
        revert();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Your contract looks fine, Could you provide transaction hash/contract address of deployment?

Comment: 0xebbe829ee7081b938bf4279f3df85666470e183fef0533b017cc18e4ecd0c689